# How can I make it so this java program will read the rest of the binary file, and not add extra spaces?

Tags: java, while-loop, binary, fileinputstream

I am trying to create a code that will take a binary file holding card data, and return the card number with spaces, and the checksum value. When I run the test cases, it will stop short of one of the test cases. How can I have it so it will finish the loop?

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CardNumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a filename");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();

        FileInputStream basic = new FileInputStream(input);
        DataInputStream inputFile = new DataInputStream(basic);
        boolean eof = false;
        long data = inputFile.readLong();
        String s;
        while (!eof) {
            try {
                while (true) {

                    s = String.valueOf(data);
                    data = inputFile.readLong();
                    System.out.print("Credit card number: ");
                    for (int i = 1; i <= s.length(); i++) {
                        System.out.print(s.charAt(i - 1));
                        if (i % 4 == 0 && i != s.length()) {
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    int sum = 0;
                    int len = s.length();
                    for (int i = len - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
                        int d = (s.charAt(i) - '0') * 2;
                        d = d % 10 + (d / 10) % 10;
                        sum += d;
                    }
                    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
                        sum += s.charAt(i) - '0';
                    }

                    System.out.println("Checksum: " + sum);
                    System.out.print("Card status: ");
                    if (sum % 10 == 0)
                        System.out.println("VALID");
                    else
                        System.out.println("INVALID");
                    //With this line of code it will not read the last line and I do not know why.

                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                eof = true;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Use an input file which has just one number in it, and step through your program using the debugger. You'll see what is going wrong.

Answer (score -2):

According to the documentation [ReadLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readLong--), reads 8 bytes and if there are fewer than 8 bytes in the input stream, it throws an EOF exception. Perhaps the last item in your binary file has fewer than 8 bytes?

Comment: The OP has a basic logic error.